# Function default parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I assume this problem is silly, but i can't find any answer. I have controller MY_Pages in core. It is a codeigniter project. Function view takes 2 parameters:

1. Page name: string
2. Data: array

   ```
   public function view($page='home', $data=[])
   {
       $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
       if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
           show_404();
       }  else {
           $this->full_view($page,$data);
       }
   }
   ```

I use this function in my other controlers

```
$this->view('info', $dane);
```

It works fine, but while I'm sending $data as a 2nd parameter, it is empty inside view function. What I'm missing?

Comment: remove the `=[]` from the function...  `public function view($page='home',$data )`

Comment: @TheDude    the `[]` signifies an Empty Array, as the default parameter. Or not....???

Comment: @Poiz, You are correct. Although it might be more accurately stated as "the default value of the parameter".

Comment: Probably a typo, but `{  else {` should be `}  else {`

Comment: if i remove =[] i have php error    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 2 for MY_Pages::view()

Filename: core/MY_Pages.php

Line Number: 28

Comment: @DFriend in my code this is ok. I dont know why after copy paste it changed

Comment: What does `var_dump($dane);` show?

Comment: This should work. Are you certain you are passing a valid variable?

Comment: @Shiv array(1) { ["title"]=> string(4) "Info" } Only this.

Comment: @DFriend $dane['info']='Information'; $this->view('info',$dane); I think so

Comment: How did you determine that `$data` "is empty inside view function"?

Comment: var_dump($dane); I get only ['title'] from it

Comment: Try the var_dump inside the function to see what is given.

Comment: I tried  if(isset($data['info']))
            {
                $data['dane']='yes';
            }
            else
            {
                $data['dane']='No';
            } gave me :array(2) { ["title"]=> string(4) "Info" ["dane"]=> string(2) "No" }

Comment: I had some bad roads in my code. Sry for the problem and thx for good intention. Ofc if u put an array like that as a default "$data=[]" it works